# What is the largest political entity that lacks legislative power?

Tags: international, legislation, local-government

Lets define some examples to clarify what I'm talking about.

- United States: has a legislature in the form of the US Congress
- New York: has a state legislature
- New York City: [can issue its own legislation](https://council.nyc.gov/legislation/)
- Manhattan: [has no legislative or executive authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_boards_of_New_York_City) on its own

So the borough of Manhattan (pop. 1.6m) does not have its own separate authority with legislative powers. Are there even bigger fully dependent political entities like this?

- “Bigger/larger” refers to the total population in the district/borough/region
- “Legislative power” refers to a set of rules that can be passed by the political entity completely independently and subsequently enforced by government authorities. So if the Manhattan borough council issues non-binding declarations, it doesn't count as "legislative power".
- Political entities that have sub entities with legislative power do not count. For example England does not have its own separate Parliament but it does have numerous cities with their own legislative powers.
- “Political entity": The Five Boroughs are the municipal corporations of New York City. While they overlap with their Counties, and are subordinate to New York City, they are legally distinct. They each have a president, council, and a district attorney. For example [Manhattan Borough President](https://www.manhattanbp.nyc.gov/). It could have a legislature, like [Suffolk County does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffolk_County,_New_York#Suffolk_County_Legislature), but it does not. As a rule of thumb, if Wiki calls this entity "borough", "county", "district", etc, then it can be considered a "political entity".

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60271/whats-the-largest-territory-where-all-power-within-the-jurisdiction-belongs-to

Comment: Presumably based on the "etc." your  list  "borough, county, district" is not exhaustive? Does _every_ traditional geographic division count? If so, England would increase the minimum to about 56 million.

Comment: @JonathanReez your additional definitions throw up some interesting questions regarding the UN Headquarters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headquarters_of_the_United_Nations, depending on whether you consider that in Manhattan or not.

Comment: @origimbo I’d say it’s not: “Although it is in New York City, the land occupied by the United Nations Headquarters and the spaces of buildings that it rents are under the sole administration of the United Nations and not the U.S. government. They are technically extraterritorial through a treaty agreement with the U.S. government.”

Comment: Since this is not a US-only question, I suspect that, rather than looking at the US, you'd want to look at political units in highly-centralized countries where the government would be unwilling to grant any law-making leeway to local entities but would still want to have say mayors running large cities.  Does the country need to be democratic?

Comment: @Italian doesn’t have to be democratic

Comment: Issue with "England has cities that cities with legistlative power".  In the UK, all legislative power comes from Parliament.  If a council has a legislative power, that is completely dependent on this power being granted by Parliament.  A council might be able to create "by-laws" but only because parliament has granted specfic licence for them to do so.  Even the Scottish parliament is gets its legislative power from Westminster.... This is not the same as a federal system.

Comment: Similarly in the case of NYC,  its legislative powers are subordinate to the state.  NYC derives its abiltiy to create laws from the city charter, which is legislation by NYS. If the charter were repealed or amended, any legislation by NYC would be void.  So NYC council is not independent at all.  It is a mechanism by which NYS creates laws for the city.

Comment: Here's a suggestion:  Tokyo metropolitian area.  Tokyo-fu includes a lot of countryside to the West (and various islands etc)  The bouroughs (Nerima, Shinjuku etc) don't have law making powers, so the "23-bouroughs" that make up the city don't have any separate legislature.  The full metro area including parts of Yokohama, Saitama and Chiba also doesn't have a legislature.  That's 30-50million

Comment: Here's a suggestion:  Tokyo metropolitian area.  Tokyo-fu includes a lot of countryside to the West (and various islands etc)  The bouroughs (Nerima, Shinjuku etc) don't have law making powers, so the "23-bouroughs" that make up the city don't have any separate legislature.  The full metro area including parts of Yokohama, Saitama and Chiba also doesn't have a legislature.  That's 30-50million

Comment: How about the national political conventions in the US.  They represent millions but cannot pass any laws.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don't know where you got that quote from, but it's wrong.  The statement that UN headquarters is "technically extraterritorial" is incorrect.  It is "inviolable," just as embassies are, and the headquarters agreement provides explicitly that federal, state, and local law apply in the headquarters district, subject to exceptions laid out in the headquarters agreement, namely that the UN can establish regulations for the headquarters district that take precedence over US law within the headquarters district.

Comment: Does charter/statute/adoption of name/emblem count as "legislation"?

Comment: @Anixx no they do not. Only the adoption of rules that regulate the lives of those who live in that location.

Comment: Well, regulation of rules can be utility tariffs, decision of reconstruction of playgrounds, organization of celebrations and festivities, establishment of a cable TV station, making a bicycle lane... Does this all count?

Comment: @Anixx no as they don't regulate how local citizens live their lives. An example of such a regulation would be a noise ordinance or a requirement to wear a helmet while riding a bicycle.

Comment: @JonathanReez noise regulations can issue even administration of dormitory or condo. Or a university campus.

Comment: @Anixx yes but only within their private property. They can't force someone to stay quiet if they set their foot on public property.

Comment: So, we are speaking about misdemeanor laws, police-enforceable fines.

Comment: @Anixx that is correct

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haidian_District in Beijing at 3,281,000 is greater than Brooklyn in population. Overal, as I see, such districts worldwide rarely exceed 2 million people.

Comment: I think, there is no reason to search for anything besides districts of megapolises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delhi, India has a legislature, however it [does not have any de-facto legislative power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi_(Amendment)_Act,_2021) as all executive decisions have to be approved by the centrally appointed Lieutenant Governor, and for all purposes, the Lieutenant Governor is considered as the government.

Delhi has a [population of 16.7M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi) as per the 2011 census, however it's likely much higher now.

Answer (score 55):

> What is the largest political entity that lacks legislative power?

The United Nations. It comprises of 193 states with two additional observer states - Vatican City and Palestine. Whilst it has a General Assembly, which can be considered as a kind of legislative body, its resolutions aren't binding and hence are considered advisory on its member states.

Comment: What about treaties created by the GA?

Comment: Perhaps the question has been changed, but I don't see how this answers the current question at all!  Its not a district, borough etc.  It certainly does have "sub entities", but it doesn't have "population", so it can't be compared to Manhatten.

Comment: @JamesK The population of the UN is the combined populations of its member countries, in the same way that the population of the US is the combined populations of its states and territories. Most of us don't think of ourselves as citizens of the UN precisely because it has so little actual power.

Comment: You don't think of yourselves as citizens of the UN because you are not!  The "population" of the UN is 193.  Individuals people are not members of the UN.  And the question seems to explictly exclude this kind of organisation.  I do think the question is somewhat hard to be definitive about, but this answer is certainly wrong!

Comment: @JamesK The members of the UN are nations, it's true, but nations are themselves populated by people. As someone in the US, I am bound by my nation's involvement in the UN. People in Germany are part of the EU even though "Germany" is the EU member listed.

Comment: “Political entities that have sub entities with legislative power do not count” since the UN is made up of nations with legislative power, this requirement would seem to rule it out

Comment: @Jame K: The headline question is 'what is the largest political entity that lacks legislative power'. The OP named Manhatten as an example. I've offered mine given the stated question.

Comment: @James K: We don't think ourselves as citizens of the UN precisely because the UN doesn't have legislative power. Nonetheless, it is a political entity.

Comment: @Divibisan: That counts out one of the OP's examples: The United States with Congress as the legislative body because he also names New York with it's own legislature and last I looked, New York was definitely part of the USA.

Comment: @Yay: I think treaties are a special case. For example, the USA under Trumps administration opted out of the Paris Agreement on Climate Change. Binding laws in England are, for example, not something that London or Manchester can opt out of.

Comment: @MoziburUllah No, you're misunderstanding the examples. He's saying that the borough of Manhattan is the example of a political entity without legislative power. It is contained within entities with legislative power, but it is the largest/highest level entity that lacks that power. The UN is like the US: an entity made up of entities with legislative powers, and thus it's not what this question is looking for

Comment: @MoziburUllah: New York is part of the U.S., but individual New Yorkers are also citizens of the US (per the Fourteenth Amendment to the U.S. Constitution). A New Yorker can even sue New York in Federal court. The U.N. has no analogous concept; for example, the International Court of Justice only settles disputes between countries.

Comment: @divisiban: No, you're wrong. He states: "New York City: Can issue its own legislation." AND I MENTIONED NEW YORK not MANHATTEN.

Answer (score 50):

> So the borough of Manhattan (pop. 1.6m) does not have its own separate authority with legislative powers. Are there even bigger fully dependent political entities like this?

There are at least two political entities that are more populous than Manhattan and certainly meet your criteria, because they are also boroughs of the city of New York: Brooklyn and Queens.

Comment: Well played good sir

Answer (score -5):

I would like to suggest: "We the People." Because the American people opt to have 'elected officials' do that 'on our behalf' [but not in our interests {legal def: profit}].

Technically speaking, Americans are each their own 'body politic' which technically, also, is a State. That is why it was founded as a 'united' body of States - before it became incorporated and '**U**nited' rather than '**u**nited'.

Some people may say this is word play or manipulating the language itself - however, ask any judge 'do words mean anything?' and you will find they absolutely do. Though most people are unaware that there are two distinct sets of definitions. There is a 'webster's dictionary' definition and is meant to be interpreted in private and/or agreeance or contracts where there is a background/context of understanding between the parties. However, absent this 'history' between parties you enter the public forum where you find debate, settlement, and dispute - and also where one finds the LEGAL definitions of the words. So yes, the words mean exactly what they are meant to mean unless we had a previous understanding or even an inside joke between us where context became irrelevant...

But I digress, I tend to ramble. I'm gonna make "**We the People**" my final answer!

Comment: Think the question refers to a pure legislative entity, which is a single role of "We the People".